# Inverse wavelet transform on wavelet coefficients

Tags: matlab, wavelet, reconstruction

I have a data set which consists of Morlet coefficients for 7 channels in 18 bands. When I try to use inverse DWT in Matlab to get the raw data in time, using this code:

```
X = idwt(Data(:(#band),:(#time),1(#channel)),[],'morl');
```

I get this error :

```
***********************************************
ERROR ...
-----------------------------------------------
 wfilters ---> The wavelet morl is not valid!
***********************************************
```

any Idea what should I do ? I'm pretty noob so any explanation is great help for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, as far as I know, there is no discrete wavelet scheme related to the `morlet` wavelet, admitting neither orthogonal nor biorthogonal implementation. See for instance the discussion in [Complex Morlet function and DWT](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/42312/15892).

Using `waveinfo('morl')`, you indeed get that: `DWT: no`

```
 Information on Morlet wavelet.
    Morlet Wavelet 
    Definition: 
    morl(x) = exp(-x^2/2) * cos(5x) 
    Family                  Morlet
    Short name              morl

    Orthogonal              no
    Biorthogonal            no
    Compact support         no
    DWT                     no
    CWT                     possible

    Support width           infinite
    Effective support       [-4 4]
    Symmetry                yes
```

So you might obtain something only (and I am not sure it is valid for your data) using some form of inverse continuous wavelet transform, for instance in Matlab  [`icwt`](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/icwt.html).